# xdotool requiring matching all options

Tags: xdotool

with xdotool I want to identify that dialog box that appears when you use a master password with Firefox.

I tried this command:

```
xdotool search --all --name "Password Required - Mozilla Firefox" --classname Firefox
```

But, it gives an error:

xdotool: Unknown command: --classname
Run 'xdotool help' if you want a command list

I´m not aware what could be wronge here, I have two options and both must match, thus I use --all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Xdotool looks for windows that match **any** condition, the default condition being `--name --classname --class`, thus these equivalent commands get all windows whose title, instance *or* class contain "foo":

```
xdotool search foo 
xdotool search --name --classname --class foo
```

[In the maintainer's words](https://github.com/jordansissel/xdotool/issues/180),

> It's a bit confusing, I'm sorry.
>
> **The `--all` and `--class` [and `--name` and `--classname`] flags act as switches and do not take arguments.**

You can, however, use [command chaining](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-xdotool/#lbAN) to do what you want:

```
xdotool search --name Password search --classname Firefox
```

The windows matched by the first `search` are "piped" onto the second `search` command.

---

Bear in mind:

- `--name` matches the window title, as in `WM_NAME` or `_NET_WM_NAME` in Xprop's output.
- `--classname` matches the first `WM_CLASS` string in Xprop's output.
- `--class` matches the second `WM_CLASS` string in Xprop's output.